# I want to finish one activity from other activity

Tags: android

I have two activity.First activity is game screen with pause button and second activity is           with resume and restart button.When i clicked pause button over Game screen then i goes to second activity from where when i clicked restart button then i want to finish first activity(Game screen) and want to start new game so this is my problem how to finish first activity please help me

Comment: just call finish();..? I'm not sure what you are really asking here.

Comment: are you sure that is correct put that buttons into separate activity? just take a look at FragmentDialog

Comment: if i will finish the activity then how to call it again through pause button i want to finish it on the button of restart on the second activity after that create this activity again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**
use Fragments

**Option 2:**
from first activity use `startActivityForResult` then when the second activity is finished cathc in `onActivityResult`. There finish the first activity then start game.

**Option 3:**
Send a broadcast message and in the first activity receive it and finish it.

There might be other options. Just put down some options which came immediately in my mind. If I were you I would use Option 1

Answer (score 3):

A suggestion would be that you register a broadcast receiver in all your activities with "finish()" in their onReceive() & whenever you wish to quit you can simple pass an intent indicating that all activities must shut down..... Although make sure that you do "unregister" the receiver in your onDestroy() methods.

something like this

```
            @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("end");
        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}


  protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
         unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
```

And when you wish to finish this from another activity just do this

```
Intent i = new Intent("end");
                sendBroadcast(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will kill all top activities and start new Activity NewGame.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewGame.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```